# Read selected node's values from kendo tree view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo treeview having a node with `{id, value}`. and I want to get selected node's id and value when I click on a button.

How can I get it? Is there any inbuilt functions there to get it?

Here is my sample code:

```
$("mytree").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: mydata,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "Id",
            });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`.select()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-select) method. Be sure to look at the other methods available as well.

```
var tv = $('.mytree').data('kendoTreeView'),
    selected = tv.select(),
    item = tv.dataItem(selected);
if (item) {
  alert('Selected item: ' + item.Name + ' : ' + item.Id + ' (uid: ' + item.uid + ')');
} else {
  alert('Nothing selected');
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NZq4A/2/)**

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for your reply. But here it is giving null for item.text and item.id is giving some Guid. I'm expecting the exact text and value which is binded through datasource.

Comment: My text/value fields in the example didn't exactly match yours. See my update and updated fiddle

Comment: Hey Ryan, I dont know what I'm doing wrong. I followed the same way, but it is giving tv.dataItem is not a function error.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I'm sorry I missed something. It is working as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
**

var tv = $("#treeview-right").data("kendoTreeView");
    var selectedNode = tv.select();
    var item = tv.dataItem(e.node);
    item.text will give you the text of the selected node.
```

**

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some description why you answered with this code so people can vote for you??

Comment: e would be undefined if you do not tie into the event handler.  @PAULDAWG     I will provide a better answer.

Comment: Works with kendoTreeList as well

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the selected answer because depending on what you actually DO, you can be 1 step behind the actually selected value.

If you had some simple delete function then this type of code works fine

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
var selectedNode = treeview.select(),
item = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode);
```

However, once you start playing with the treeview more you will end up regretting that as I have.

**Best practice is to tie to the event handler**

e.g.

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    expanded: true,
    select: onSelect,
    ....        
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

**select** **function**

```
function onSelect(e) {

    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var item = treeview.dataItem(e.node);

     if (item) {
         console.log('Selected item: ' + item.whatever + ' | Id = ' + item.Id + ' | Type = ' + item.Type);
         var someVariable = item.whatever;
     } else{
        console.log('nothing selected');
     }
```